# How to set the value of a column to equal another column if multiple conditions meet?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like with ID and multiple events and a start date. I would like to make the end date the same as the start date of the next event in order or null if the next event doesn't have a start date.

```
ID event start      end
1  a     01/01/21
1  b     02/01/21
1  c     03/01/21
1  d     04/01/21
1  e     
2  b     05/01/21
2  c     01/01/21
2  a     02/01/21
2  d     04/01/21
2  e     
3  e
3  b     01/01/21
3  d     02/01/21
3  a     04/01/21
3  c     04/01/21
```

if Id 1 and event b has a start date, I would like that to be the end date for Id 1 and event a.
So basically every next event start date would be the previous events end date for the same Id and I would like to iterate over an entire data frame.

I would like the dataframe to look like

```
ID event start      end
1  a     01/01/21 01/01/21
1  b     02/01/21 03/01/21
1  c     03/01/21 04/01/21
1  d     04/01/21
1  e     
2  b     05/01/21 01/01/21
2  c     01/01/21 04/01/21
2  a     02/01/21 05/01/21
2  d     04/01/21
2  e     
3  e
3  b     01/01/21 04/01/21
3  d     02/01/21
3  a     04/01/21 01/01/21
3  c     04/01/21 02/01/21
```

I tried working towards using a for loop like this but I can't get it to work.

```
for s in data["ID"]:
    row = data[(data["ID"] == s) & (data["event"] == "a")]
    if row["Start_Date"].isnull == True:
        pass
    else:
        row1 = data[(data["ID"] == s) & (data["event"] == "b")]
        if row1["start"].isnull == True:
            pass
        else:
            row["end"] = row1["start"]
```

Is there a better way to do this or am I on the right track but my execution is off? How can I achieve the dataframe that I want? any help would be appreciated.

Edit: the events are not always in an order hence why I tried using a loop to go through each row and manually check for the specific event in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by sorting your dataframe by your 2 columns, ID and event in `ascending` order using `sort_values()`. Then, you can use `groupby` with `shift()` to get the start date of the previous event, and assign it as the end of the next event.

To keep the structure of your dataframe the same (since we are sorting values but we want to revert back to the original `index`), in our first step let's create a list that will be the the `index` that we can use at the end. This way we make sure that we keep the original structure of the dataset.

Put together in code:

```
# Store your initial index
s = df.index.tolist()

# Sort values by ID and Event in ascending order
df.sort_values(by=['ID','event'],ascending=[True,True],inplace=True)

# Get the end date, which is the start date of the previous event
df['end']=df.groupby('ID')['start'].shift(-1)

# Make sure your columns are dates
df['start'] , df['end']  = df['start'].dt.date , df['end'].dt.date
df.fillna('',inplace=True)

# Reindex to get the initial structure
df.reindex(s)
```

Will get you back your desired outcome:

```
    ID event       start         end
0    1     a  2021-01-01  2021-01-02
1    1     b  2021-01-02  2021-01-03
2    1     c  2021-01-03  2021-01-04
3    1     d  2021-01-04            
4    1     e                        
5    2     b  2021-01-05  2021-01-01
6    2     c  2021-01-01  2021-01-04
7    2     a  2021-01-02  2021-01-05
8    2     d  2021-01-04            
9    2     e                        
10   3     e                        
11   3     b  2021-01-01  2021-01-04
12   3     d  2021-01-02            
13   3     a  2021-01-04  2021-01-01
14   3     c  2021-01-04  2021-01-02
```

Comment: While this is actually useful to know, it's not quite what I'm looking for. I neglected to add that the events could be in a random order. I apologise about that, it slipped my mind, hence why I tried using a loop function. But I very much appreciate this, it actually helps me understand groupby a bit more!

Comment: Glad it was helpful. I updated my answer to adjust your new requirements.

Comment: Thanks so much, that actually does what I need!